# swift UIActivityIndicatorView .hidden = false not working

Tags: swift, xcode6, uiactivityindicatorview, xcode6-beta7

I am trying to show an Activity Indicator View once a button is pressed, but it does not want to show. If I don't set it to hidden at all, it shows, and when I try hide it, it hides. But if it is hidden, it will not show again.

Here is the code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    loading.hidden = true
}

@IBAction func submit() {
    loading.hidden = false
    loading.startAnimating()
    if chosenCategory == "" || txtName.text == "" || txtEmail.text == ""    {
        loading.stopAnimating()
        loading.hidden = true
    } else {
        println("animation")
```

No matter what, the stop animation works, and it can hide, but no matter what I do, it just seems to skip the `loading.hidden = false` and goes straight to printing the message out.

What could be happening?

Comment: There is no waiting here - every line that is in the same function, unless you're using something like a sleep() or some kind of asynchronous call, will be executed immediately one after the other.  It's not like loading.startAnimating() will be called, things will go on hold, and then a while later the rest will happen.  They will happen almost instantaneously one after the other.  Show us more code for context.

Comment: No, there is waiting, the `...` is where other code goes. It calls to a server, and there is a waiting period (the request). And then I have even tried them in different methods

Comment: Show us the rest of the code - can't help you otherwise.

Comment: There is alot of code, over 200 lines. But I will try post what is relevant...

Comment: No offense but you seem to have a history of posting questions that don't get answers :)  You should consider how you're asking/what code you're providing more generally on SO.

Comment: They are legit questions with proper issues though that I cannot figure out. It's not my fault other people don't want to help.

Comment: When submit is hit, if the if statement is true, you will immediately hide loading.  And people do want to help, but you need to provide enough information.

Answer (score 17):

I would recommend not using the **.hidden** property at all. Use the **.hidesWhenStopped** property instead and set it to **true**. Then simply invoke the **.startAnimating()** method and the UIActivityIndicatorView will automatically become visible and will be animating. Invoke the **.stopAnimating()** method and the UIActivityIndicatorView will automatically hide.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    loading.hidesWhenStopped = true //this is all you need to change
}

@IBAction func submit() {
    loading.startAnimating() // becomes visible
    if chosenCategory == "" || txtName.text == "" || txtEmail.text == ""    {
        loading.stopAnimating() // goes into hiding
    } else {
        println("animation")
```

Comment: I thought toggling the hidden property is same as start/stopAnimating() if I set hidesWhenStopped to YES... but I am wrong. using start/stopAnimating() works great.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer, `hidden`property is simply not working for `UIActivityIndicatorView`. I'm quite frustated that people answer questions here without even have tested problem at hand.

Answer (score 6):

Use the GCD (Grand Central Dispatch) routines:

```
    self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    self.activityIndicator.hidden = false

    dispatch_after(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, dispatch_get_main_queue(), { ()->() in
        ... // your long running code here

        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    })
```